# Send text to a search box which is a hidden element with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
 <input type="text" autocomplete=off autocorrect=off class="select-input" Id="myid_bus21" tabindex="0">
```

Id's of last 2 characters change for each link I use. Hence I used

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(I'd, 'myid_bus')]").send_keys('hoqq')
```

> Error: cannot focus element

**However I am able to send keys using the full id:**

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ I'd = "myid_bus21"]')
```

**Also i am able to send keys via**

```
driver.find_element_by_id("myid_bus21")
```

**As my I'd is changing for each link I am unable to locate the element**

Comment: I'm agree with JeffC in any case try to do a find_elements_by_xpath, in this way you can see all the element with that xpath and you can identify which one are the hidden one and which one is the one that you are searching, this kind of errors happen, more if you are in a page with multiple tabs where the element are just hidden

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when you use a partial id, it's not unique on the page and the first one that is found is not visible, thus the error. Without a link to the site or more HTML, it's hard to propose a solution. You would need to get the collection of elements using the partial id and then search for the one (or more) that are visible and then try to use it. There's no way to know if that fits your scenario without more information on the page.